# How is one to multiplex buffered IO in C?

Tags: c, select

I'm working on a simple chat server in C. In order to get incoming messages from all of my clients, I need to use the `select` system call. I've decided I wanted to make use of the `stdio` functions to make it easier, but I've concerned that the buffering of the library will mess up the use of `select` (i.e data will remain buffered, read from the fd but not visible). What function should be used to multiplex buffered I/O in C?

As I was writing this, I remembered that file streams can be put into unbuffered mode. Would that work?

Comment: You still have the socket descriptors don't you? Or do you just throw them away after you've done `fdopen` on them? In that case you can use `fileno` to get them back, and still use `select` to multiplex.

Comment: Functions from stdio like `scanf` and `read` might read more data than is currently available and block. They do not play well with `select`.

Comment: @user4815162342 yeah, I just misunderstood what he said

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I do still have the descriptors, but I just figured that since it's bad practice to mix calls to `write` _and_ `fprintf` it could be a bad idea to mix `select` and `fgets`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, unbuffered mode won't help. For example, `fgets()` will want to read as much data as necessary until a whole line is read (or the user-provided buffer is filled up). To do this, it will call the underlying `read()` more than once, even when unbuffered, and the calls after the first one will not be under your control. The same applies to `fscanf()` and `fprintf()`, and even to `fread()` and `fwrite()`.

If you really insist on using stdio, you can perform blocking IO in multiple threads, but that's not worth the trouble (and potential system overload). The only sane way to use multiplexed IO is to use the low-level reading operations to read the data, and then parse it using stdio tools such as `sscanf`.

Comment: Although I think it should be noted that `select` has an upper limit on the value of the file descriptor it can take: "An fd_set is a fixed size buffer.  Executing FD_CLR() or FD_SET() with a value of fd that is negative or is equal to or larger than FD_SETSIZE will result in undefined behavior." [Check it](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html#NOTES).

Comment: @JeremyRodi Noted, but I don't think I'll have a problem with using too many clients

Comment: @JeremyRodi In the context of this question, what applies to `select()` also applies to its better replacements, such as `poll()`, `epoll()`, kqeue, etc. `select()` merely enables event-driven programming and IO processing which stdio is fundamentally incompatible with.

Comment: @user4815162342 I understand that; I just wanted to make the asker aware of that limitation, regardless of what would be compatible with stdio.

Comment: @JeremyRodi On the other hand, it should also be noted that one has to multiplex hundreds of file descriptors to even approach the limit of `select()` (`FD_SETSIZE` is 1024 on today's Linux systems). Thus it's unlikely to be an issue in practice, except for professional developers of high-load servers.

Comment: @user4815162342 The documentation says a value of a fd that is equal to or larger than `FD_SETSIZE`; because of that, he doesn't even need 1024 fds in the `fd_set` for it to cause undefined behaviour; all he needs is an fd to have a value higher than 1024, and it causes undefined behaviour.  While I concede that it is unlikely that it would be approached, I felt that it should be noted.